# How can I smooth my meshes?

Tags: mesh

[image]

I'm working on smoothing this mesh of a neuron from our lab. I've done Quadratic Edge Collapse Decimation; however, the surface still does not look smooth. Any ideas for how I could fix this? You can download the original mesh [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=17cH0-aNLwNlzrp4cazhuARdT1Bigrxe2) in case it's helpful. It is from research that is not published yet so please don' share it outside this thread. Appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: First things that come to mind are select object in object mode and (in Blender 2.80) right click>  "shade smooth". Another thing that comes to mind is select the object in object mode  and Ctrl+1, or Ctrl+2, or Ctrl+3, which adds a subdivision surface modifier. With object selected Ctrl+0 will reset the modifier in viewport back to 0. If you want to get rid of the modifier altogether, go over to the object panel and delete the modifier, otherwise it might still render with modifier on unless at the modifier you put render to 0. I'm still kind of new to Blender. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the [*Subdivision Surface*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/subdivision_surface.html?highlight=subdivision%20surface#subdivision-surface-modifier) modifier alongside [*smooth shading*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html?highlight=smooth%20shading#shading).

Using the subdivision surface modifier creates additional polygons, which is bad for games.